# How to hide toggle div when clicking anywhere on the page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visibility

I Hide/Show elements with .toggle()

```
 <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 250px;z-index:7">
   <div  class="Search" style="display: none;" >
    <table width="100%" style="border: 1px solid #fff; border-radius:5px;padding:15px">
      <tr>
      <td>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="CategoryDropDownList" runat="server" />
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div id="showSreachDiv">
   <a style="cursor: pointer">
    <img src="images/btnSearch.png" /></a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

with jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#showSreachDiv").click(function () { $(".Search").toggle("slow"); });
     });
```

When i click my div, show toggle div.

But i want, hide toggle div when  clicking anywhere on the page.

I use this code

```
 $(function () {

         // body click
         $("body").click(function () {

             // element to toggle
             var $el = $(".Search");

             // toggle div
             if ($el.is(":visible")) {
                 // fade out
                 $el.fadeOut(200);
             } else {
                 // fade in
                 $el.fadeIn(200);
             }

         });
     });
```

But it show and hide toogle div when i click my div.

Comment: But an opaque overlay between page your div, then listen to the clicks on it - that would be simpler.

Comment: toggle the DIV inside document.click event, it will get fire when click the DIV itself.

Comment: to really get a solid understanding of what's happening here you should read up on Event Delegation in general. Here's a link from Jquery: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to stop the event bubbling to the document `e.stopPropagation()`:

[**chekout fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WxcLV/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#showSreachDiv").click(function (e) { //<--------pass here
      e.stopPropagation(); // <--------------stop here
      $(".Search").toggle("slow");
  });
  $(document).click(function () { // you don't need the else part to fadeout
      var $el = $(".Search");
      if ($el.is(":visible")) {
          $el.fadeOut(200);
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an hotfix, check that the target element is not the element you want to hide:

```
$("body").click(function (event) {

    // element to toggle
    var $el = $(".Search");

    if( event.target == $el[0])
        return;

    ...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to stop event propagation once clicked on 'showSreachDiv'

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showSreachDiv').click(function(evt) {
        $(".Search").toggle("slow");
        evt.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function(){
        $(".Search").toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. But i want to `hide` toggle div when clicking anywhere on the page.

Comment: This isn't a solution, it defeats the purpose of trying to toggle 'out' when clicking the document, because it also toggles 'in' when the document is clicked anywhere. You might want to update your answer.